# Augmented Reality Help

Tags: image-processing, augmented-reality

I need a help to develop a small application on Augmented Reality.I have spend almost a week trying but with no proper solution.Tried some sample code but still not successful.
I have seen many videos and want to develop something like that.
for example my code should detect only square or any particular shape.And then after detecting the square and another Image should appear on the screen.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff is hard, but most new cool things are until they are no longer cool or new.

You can play with [AR Toolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/) until you are familiar with the functionality and then attempt to dive into the setting and mess with those, then maybe look at the source.